# Как получить доступ к сессии в RouteServiceProvider?

Tags: laravel, сессия

Ввожу в курс дела: если в роут приходит id заказа - я пытаюсь достать его из БД. Если в БД его нет - пытаюсь достать данные заказа из сессии. Вся эта магия происходит в RouteServiceProvider::boot:

```
$router->model('order', 'App\Order', function ($id) {
    return new \App\Order(['order' => $id]);
});
```

Однако, когда я пытаюсь достать в замыкании данные из сессии, например так:

```
Session::all()
```

получаю пустой массив. Однако, уже к экшене контроллера данные сессии доступны. И в шаблоне, соответственно, тоже доступны.

Вариант в каждом экшене контроллера заполнять данными пустую модель попахивает костылем. Может кто-нибудь подсказать решение?

Laravel 5.2.35. Настройки сессии - по умолчанию, я их не менял.

Answer (score 1):

В провайдерах сессия не доступна. Из документации:

> Service providers are the central place of all Laravel application
>   bootstrapping. Your own application, as well as all of Laravel's core
>   services are bootstrapped via service providers.

Тоесть провайдеры таки отвечают за подгрузку сесси.

Что касается костыля - все твои контролеры наследуются от класса `Controller` - в его конструкторе и помести всю свою магию.

Comment: 1. Идея в том, что у меня модель, которую надо заполнить данными из сессии, передается только в некоторые экшены контроллера, и только по определенным роутам.И таскать эту модель с собой всегда и везде - мне не нужно.  

2. RouteServiceProvider который в App в списке провайдеров стоит последним. Т.е. провайдер сессии грузится перед ним. Но при этом сессия то все равно не доступна. Т.е. есть подозрение, что после выполнения всех провайдеров отрабатывает еще какой-то механизм, который инициализирует сессии.